# Firefox: No stylesheets are displaying for any web pages

Tags: firefox

Strange bug just popped up for me today.  No CSS is being applied to any web pages in firefox.

Version is 15.0.1

I have tried starting in safe mode, but problem persists

I have verified the View > Page Style is still set to basic.

What could be happening here?

Thanks for any help

Here's and example of what google like:

[image: Google without CSS]

Comment: Do you have any extensions that may affect stylesheets on all websites?

Comment: @Jay, As I said, I tried starting it in safe mode, which disables all extensions, and the problem persisted.  I also tried clearing everything from cache/cookies, as well as restarting my machine.  All to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not afraid of losing any extensions/plugins/settings/preferences, then delete your current profile and make a new one. This will reset everything.

1. Right-click on your Firefox shortcut and go to Properties.
2. At the end of the target field, type in a space followed by `-P`, press OK.
3. Start Firefox and the profile manager should come up. Delete your current profile and make a new one.
4. Exit from the profile manager and then change the Firefox shortcut back to how it was.
5. Open Firefox and everything will be reset back to default.

Answer (score 1):

**First** check this Mozilla Firefox Troubleshooting help page

[Troubleshoot and diagnose Firefox problems](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-and-diagnose-firefox-problems):

**Then** check if the problem is limited only to one Firefox profile or all of them by creating a new Firefox profile:

Add this command line (or the equivalent in your system) in a shortcut:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -profilemanager`

**Finally** try in an other Windows user account to check if the problem is limitated to your current account or for the entire system...